# attributeError : module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'CRS'

Tags: python, pyproj

#### map dbscan

```
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
import pyproj
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
```

```
crs_4326 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:4326') # Latitude Longitude system
crs_3857 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:3857') # Marcetorsystem
```

used this command to download pyproj:
`use conda install -c conda-forge pyproj`

Comment: I guess it's pyproj.crs.CRS

Comment: What version of pyproj? `pyproj.CRS` requires 2+.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It's true that pyproj needs to be 2.6 but my anaconda won't let me update it. On prompt it says its 2.6 but my navigator shows it being 1.9. Not sure how to solve this issue... May try to redownload anaconda again.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. I was using pyproj version 2.6.0

Updating the package to latest version available solved it.