# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.crs.crs'; 'pyproj.crs' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, osmnx, pyproj

I am trying to import a networkx graph object as a pickle using nx.read_gpickle, and am getting an error that pyproj.crs package does not exist. Heads up that I am using [GOSTnets](https://github.com/worldbank/GOSTnets), a package developed for network analysis using networkx, geopandas, osmnx, and peartree.

I first constructed the graph, and then projected using osmnx.project_graph and saved using GOSTnets.save:

```
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)

# save Graph as pickle using GOSTnets.save:
gn.save(G_proj,'processed_graph_cleaned_part1_proj','./', pickle = True, edges = False, nodes = False)

# save in networkx terms:
wpath = r"MYPATH"
savename = 'processed_graph_cleaned_part1_proj'
nx.write_gpickle(G, os.path.join(wpath, '%s.pickle' % savename))
```

then in another notebook, I try to import the graph:

```
import os, sys, time, importlib

import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import GOSTnets as gn

# make sure osmium is installed (pip install osmium)
# An internal function called when creating the OSM_to_Network object will import osmium
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import osmnx as ox

# import Graph pickle
G = nx.read_gpickle(r"MYPATH\processed_graph_cleaned_part1_proj.pickle")
```

When doing so, I receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-2be4f8fabb58> in <module>
      1 # read graph
      2 # this graph is the
----> 3 G = nx.read_gpickle(r"MYPATH\processed_graph_cleaned_proj.pickle")

<decorator-gen-748> in read_gpickle(path)

C:\WBG\Anaconda\envs\test_gostNets\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _open_file(func_to_be_decorated, *args, **kwargs)
    238         # Finally, we call the original function, making sure to close the fobj
    239         try:
--> 240             result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
    241         finally:
    242             if close_fobj:

C:\WBG\Anaconda\envs\test_gostNets\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\gpickle.py in read_gpickle(path)
     99     .. [1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html
    100     """
--> 101     return pickle.load(path)
    102 
    103 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.crs.crs'; 'pyproj.crs' is not a package
```

I have pyproj  version: 2.4.2.post1, build: py36hc1560cf_1. Networkx version: 2.4. Running with conda in jupyter. Does anyone have an idea of what is happening? Apologies if a duplicate question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you already follow the [tour]? Please also read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), since you didn't include a [mre]. Adding it would be very helpful.

Comment: hi @wovano, thank you for the heads up. I added a code example and more details.

Comment: @jbelanger thanks for adding more code. Can you extend the code how you create the save file? Then we can reproduce your error and propose solutions. From the current information, I would guess you need to import [pyproj (?)](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/api/crs/crs.html) in your notebook where you load the savefile.

Comment: hi @Sparky05, thanks for your response. The error persists after importing pyproj. Please note in edited post that I am using a python wrapper for networkx/osmnx/geopands/peartree called GOSTnets. however the issue seems to be related to the osmnx projected graph. All other non-projected graphs import fine in the same conda environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of pyproj. For example, the current release of OSMnx [requires](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/v0.15.1/requirements.txt) pyproj>=2.6. Version 2.4 does not have the CRS module you are trying to use. Make sure you install OSMnx according to its [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation).

This is similar to the question answered here: [Cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj' for using the osmnx library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658167/cannot-import-name-crs-from-pyproj-for-using-the-osmnx-library/62958055#62958055)

Comment: thanks very much for the helpful answer. Per the installation instructions - do i have to create a new ox environment, or can i update an existing one instead? i saw from related question you shared that i can't simply `conda/pip install osmnx/pyproj`.

Comment: I'd recommend you create a new environment to keep it nice and clean. Install all the packages you want in it in the single line when you create it.

Comment: NB, this also seems in line with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61797506/10669875) on a similar/related question.

Comment: thanks very much @gboeing & @wovano! the new env with updated osmnx solved the problem :)